# Trigger created with compilation errors due to PLS-00049: bad bind variable

Tags: plsql

I have written below code for testing the auditing on emp table.
But don't know why am I getting the error PLS-00049: bad bind variable

```
create table audit_emp_values (Username varchar2(30), Time timestamp, old_salary number, new_salary number);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_emp_values
AFTER delete or update or insert on employee
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
     insert into audit_employee_table values (user, sysdate, :old.old_salary, :new.new_salary);
End;
/
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err;
Errors for TRIGGER AUDIT_EMP_VALUES:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/58     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.OLD_SALARY'
2/75     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_SALARY'
```

Comment: Do you have columns in employee tables as old_salary and new_salary?

Comment: Please give your employee table defination @Nav

Comment: It may be salary column in your employee table

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the error. Below is the correct code.

```
create table audit_employee_table (Username varchar2(30), Time timestamp, old_salary number, new_salary number);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_emp_values
AFTER delete or update or insert on employee
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
     insert into audit_employee_table values (user, sysdate, :OLD.salary, :NEW.salary);
End;
/
```